# IBM Worklight - Debug a Worklight Autenticator and/or Login Module

Tags: debugging, logging, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a custom Autenticator in a Worklight hybrid project like this

```
public class MyCustomAuthenticator implements WorkLightAuthenticator{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyCustomAuthenticator.class.getName());

    private Map<String, Object> authenticationData = null;

    public void init(Map<String, String> options) throws MissingConfigurationOptionException {
        logger.info("MyCustomAuthenticator initialized");
    }
    ...
}
```

But I don't see where does Worklight put those logger messages. Am I missing something?

Comment: What server is the project deployed to? WAS? Tomcat?

Comment: It isn't deployed, I'm testing it in Worklight Studio.

Comment: The info center documentation says that the logs messages are put in Studio Console as well as in server.log and audit.log. I have looked at those files and had not luck

Comment: What is your Worklight version?

Answer (score 1):

In your server/conf folder look for the development.logging.properties file and uncomment the following properties:

```
 com.worklight.level = FINE
 java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = FINE
```

Then see if the logs appear in your development console.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this new instructional video, "Logging and Debugging in Worklight Server", will help you to debug your Java code:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmWBrCilt3Q

The shown in the video assumes you are using Worklight 6.0.

Also see:

- [Worklight 5.0.6.1 - System.out.println() logging from Worklight adapter is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947323/worklight-5-0-6-1-system-out-println-logging-from-worklight-adapter-is-not-w)

  In JavaScript you can use `WL.Logger`.

  In Java you can use `logger.info` or `logger.warning` by importing java.util.logging.Logger.
  logger.info / logger.warning will be printed to the Eclipse Worklight console.

Answer (score 0):

What is the worklight version?
If it 5.0.5 and above, after activating your project, the logs should be in 
...WorklightServerHome\PROJECT_NAME\logs