# IBM Worklight 5.0.6 - Adapter Logging

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

I would like to log the Worklight server log in adapters. I have turned "audit" = true in adapter XML and used WL.Logger.log("Here is my log") to test the logging.

In WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\server1\SystemOut.log, I can see the following log:

```
[2013/8/3   21:36:28:581 CST] 000000bb JavaScriptInt I   com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation log Here is my log
[2013/8/3   21:36:31:225 CST] 0000006b AuditBean     I  audit User 'Unknown' invoked procedure 'Adapter.getData' with parameters {
   "arr": [
   ]
}
```

My question is that:

(1) Can I create a log file which only logs these Worklight server log? Is there any log4j.properties in Worklight which I can set this info? I have searched around the information center and it tells me to reference to Websphere application server logging. But I believe I shall configure this in Worklight?

(2) Can Worklight server HTTP session can be logged as well?

Many thanks.

Environment: Worklight 5.0.6.1, WAS ND 8.5

Answer (score 0):

1. Starting Worklight 5.0.5, Worklight no longer uses `Log4j`, rather `JUL` (Java Util Logging) is used. This means that you have to do it in the tools of the application server that you use.

   I've found the following: [Adding custom handlers, filters, and formatters](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rtrb_cbeusecustom.html).
   Perhaps what you can do in WAS is to add the above and filter `com.worklight`.
2. I do not fully understand this, can you elaborate? Until then,
   Try to use a 3rd party application such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Thanks. For #1, I will try to look it into details. For #2, what I mean is that I would like to log the HTTP session for the request to Worklight server as well. For example, when a user invokes "TestAdapter", it is actually making a request to Worklight server through http request. Is it possible to log the HTTP session as well?

Comment: By the way I have Java classes and I want to know if I can put logging inside these classes. I've found this but I guess it's not the way to do it WorklightServerLogger logger = new WorklightServerLogger(CustomLdapLoginModule.class, MessagesBundles.EXTENSION_API);

Comment: @HoucemBerrayana, this does not belong to this question. Try the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947323/worklight-5-0-6-1-system-out-println-logging-from-worklight-adapter-is-not-w